# Is scipy.integrate.quad suitable for integrating a matrix expression?

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to integrate a matrix function in Python, using the scipy `quad` function. Is this suitable for matrix integration or is there a better function to use?

The integrand is defined as:

```
def integrand(x, W, Omega, omega, K, R):

    return np.real(np.dot(W,np.dot(expm(1j*(Omega-omega*np.identity(2))*x+K*x+R*x),np.ones([2,1]))))
```

and I'm integrating using `quad` as follows:

```
def integral(W, Omega, K, R, omega):

    return quad(integrand, 0, np.inf, args=(W, Omega, omega, K, R))[0]
```

For the input values I specify, I checked that the integrand is valid. I believe the integral does exist, but quad returns `nan`, so I wonder if `quad` is not suitable for this sort of integration?

The full code is:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import expm
from scipy.integrate import quad

def integrand(x, W, Omega, omega, K, R):

    return np.real(np.dot(W,np.dot(expm(1j*(Omega-omega*np.identity(2))*x+K*x+R*x),np.ones([2,1]))))

def integral(W, Omega, K, R, omega):

    return quad(integrand, 0, np.inf, args=(W, Omega, omega, K, R))[0]

Rb = 250
a = 0.5
Rf = 23
k = 200
wf = 250
wb = wf

omega = 0

W = np.array([a,1-a])
Omega = np.array([[wf,0],[0,wb]])
K = np.array([[-k,k],[k,-k]])
R = np.array([[Rf,0],[0,Rb]])


print(integral(W, Omega, K, R, omega))
```

The result is as follows:

```
python3.6/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py:364: IntegrationWarning: The occurrence of roundoff error is detected, which prevents
  the requested tolerance from being achieved.  The error may be
  underestimated.
  warnings.warn(msg, IntegrationWarning)
nan
```

Comment: I wonder if the `np.inf` integration limit is causing problems.  It's one thing to handle such a boundary analyticallly, quite another to approach it numerically.  But I don't know the details of `quad` (or the underlying library code) to know if has special tricks.

Comment: If I replace the `np.inf `with `1` I get a `-4e69` result.  And values quickly become bigger as I increase that bound.

Comment: The results with bound `1`, would surely imply that the integration isn't working even without the `np.inf` bound, although I agree that `np.inf` could also cause issues?

Comment: I have no idea of what kinds of values `integrand` should produce, so you'll have to do your own digging.